# three.js: Access Scene Objects by Name or ID

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm generating objects from an array which I've defined like this (It's not limited to these three):

```
var links = [['Linkedin','img/linkedin.png','-300','-230', '600'],
             ['Google+', 'img/google.png',  '0',   '-230', '600'],
             ['Twitter', 'img/twitter.png', '300', '-230', '600']];
```

Now it goes through the each loop to create and add the objects to the scene by Three.JS like this:

```
$.each(links, function(i, item) {
    var thisItemTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(item[1]);
    thisItemGeo = new THREE.CubeGeometry(60, 60, 60,1 ,1 , 1);
    thisItemMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: thisItemTexture });
    thisItem =    new THREE.Mesh(thisItemGeo, thisItemMat);
    scene.add(thisItem);
    thisItem.position.x = item[2];
    thisItem.position.y = item[3];
    thisItem.position.z = item[4];
    thisItem.castShadow = true;
    thisItem.receiveShadow = true;          
});
```

The question is:
 How can I access the objects that I've made in the each loop above?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. What you want to do, is keep a reference to each `thisItem` right? Is it possible, that a list of items can be obtained from `scene` ?

Comment: @tobi I want to access the list of objects that are in the `scene` somehow.

Comment: It seems, that `scene.children` contains a list of the objects in a scene.

Comment: @tobi I think, it's not a suitable approach of doing that. Maybe there is some parameters which I can give to each object in the loop. Then it might possible to access that objects through that parameter. Something like an id.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can do this:

```
myObject.name = "objectName";
...
var object = scene.getObjectByName( "objectName" );
```

or to recursively search the scene graph

```
var object = scene.getObjectByName( "objectName", true );
```

Alternatively, you can search by ID.

```
var object = scene.getObjectById( 4, true );
```

three.js r.61

Comment: For the purpose of making object changes, would you recommend that the OP store an array of object IDs?

Comment: @LucianNovo Please make a new post if you have a question.

Comment: No, but `getObjectByName()` may not be useful to you if the object names are not unique. Remember, you also have `Object3D.userData`, which is an object to which you are free to add custom properties. For example, `myObject.userData.name = "foo";`.