# How to access loaded model with objectLoader

Tags: three.js

I am trying to load an external model using ObjectLoader. I am using the following code

```
loader.load( 'teapot.obj', function ( object ) {

        globalobject=object;
        object.traverse( function ( child ) {

            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                child.material.map = texture;
                console.log(child);
                child.position.x = 3;
                child.position.y = -6;
                child.position.z = -17;
                child.scale.x=.04;
                child.scale.y=.04;
                child.scale.z=.04;
                child.name='tea';
                scene.add( child );

            }

        });
```

But when I try to access this object in my render method using the following code it shows error

```
scene.getObjectByName('tea').rotation.z+=.01;
```

I saw using console that `scene.getObjectByName('tea')` is `undefined` 
I can use all other standard Mesh objects using the above command but what is the problem with my object loaded using loader?
Can anyone help me to get the way?

Comment: you are assigning the same name to all of your child objects.

Comment: How can I do it then

Comment: I also tried using the following code object.name='tea' but same result i got

Comment: it should be `globalobject.name='tea'`

Comment: can you create a fiddle to see why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple childs in one obj file then append some number to differentiate between multiple mesh. 
Then this should work:

```
scene.getObjectByName( "objectName" );
```

[This answer may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426559/three-js-access-scene-objects-by-name-or-id)