# How to select a THREE Mesh programmatically

Tags: three.js

I know of the traditional picking and raycasting models to select a mesh inside of a THREE scene, but I'd like to pick a mesh given an ID for testing purposes.

For example:

- Uer select mesh 1 (or some other ID like 'exampleName', etc.)

Any ideas on how to select/click a mesh programmatically?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426559/three-js-access-scene-objects-by-name-or-id

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Yes, that works for getting the object, but I'd like to actually select/click it. Is there a way one can programmatically click it with the unique identifier?

Comment: **1)** Search for how to find an object under a mouse click. There are a couple ways to do it, including `GPU Picking` and `Raycasting`. **2)** All three.js `Mesh` objects (actually all `Object3D` objects) have an [`id`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.id) property, which is a (run-time) unique identifier.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, we'd get an ID after clicking an object. I'd like to click an object given an ID

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood the question. Please reconsider the information WestLangley provided. Once you have the object, you can set its "selected" state (however you do that). You're basically skipping the "click" step, and jumping straight into setting the state. If you logic handles this differently, then we'll need to understand how that works in order to help you, which means providing more code and context.