# How to get the id of an object in react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am trying to get the `id` of an object I created in [react-three-fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber). I tried to use `document.getElementById` but have not been successful.

Here is my object I created:

```js
 const createFace = () => {
    let face = [];
    let size = props.cubeArr[0].length;
    for (let row = 0; row < size; row++) {
      let rowArr = [];
      for (let col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        let position = [col - 1, size - 2 - row, 0];
        rowArr[col] = (
          <Cell
            key={`${props.side}-${row}-${col}`}
            id={`${props.side}-${row}-${col}`}
            position={position}
          />
        );
      }
      face[row] = <group key={`${props.side}-${row}`}>{rowArr}</group>;
```

I did not include the rest of the three.js code for brevity, but essentially I am setting an `id` to each of my `Cells` and I would like to access these 3D `Cells` based on their ID so I can run `click` functions.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426559/three-js-access-scene-objects-by-name-or-id) but can't see how to translate it to react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three.js objects have this optional [property called `.name`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.name). You can assign names to your Meshes, and then you can access them with `.getObjectByName()`. It's a clean alternative that frees you of React's sloppy `useRef` approach:

```js
// First you assign a name to the object
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.name = "mySpecialMesh";

// ...

// Then later on you can find this object by the name you assigned
const sameMesh = scene.getObjectByName("mySpecialMesh");
```

I pressume you could do something similar with `<Cell name="mySpecialMesh" />`

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after posting this, I found some answers that refer to using the `useRef` hook on my groups.

This implementation works, but not sure if its the most appropriate way of going about this. Anyways, as of now this method works

```js
import React, {useRef} from 'react'

const Cell = (props) => {

   let cellRef = useRef();

   const clickSurroundingCell = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation()
      let cubeObject = cellRef.current.parent.parent.parent // get main parent to check all objects
      // clicking on the cell reference here
      let cellToClick = cubeObject.children[0].children[0].children[0] 
      cellToClick.__r3f.handlers.onClick(event) // this executes the referenced cell onClick function
  }

  return (
      <Plane onClick={clickSurroundingCell}>
      </Plane>
  )
}
```